# graphicsmagick - how to pipe two commands using standard in- & output

Tags: pipe, std, graphicsmagick

I would like to connect two different graphicsmagick commands using pipe, just as an example  create a tiled image and after this is done add a border. What i understood from the manual "-" should be used as standard input or output, so this is what i tried:

```
gm montage -geometry +20+20 -tile 2x2 /home/pi/*.jpg - | gm convert -border 150x150 - /home/pi/test.jpg
```

But for reasons i don't understand it breaks with this error message:

```
gm montage: No encode delegate for this image format (-) [No such file or directory].
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any hint would be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying a file-type to send through stdin/stdout, such as `MIFF` (Magick Image File Format) which will preserve all meta-data and losslessly-encode the image in the pipe:

```
gm montage -tile 2x2 *.jpg miff:- | gm convert miff:- -border 150x150 result.png
```

You can also use `PNG:-` or `JPEG:-`, by the way - it's just that `MIFF` is best.

Comment: Cool. What about getting gm convert to output to stdout ?